# How to find nearest timestamp by comparing two array

Tags: php, datetime

I have two arrays lets say `$data['Occur']` and `$data['Reset']`

`$data['Occur']` is an array consist of timestamps of some event occurrence and

`$data['Reset']` is an array consist of timestamps of **reset** same occurrence

What i have to do is find respective **reset** timestamp for event occur.

for example:

if event occur at "**2013-10-01 00:50:27**" and it is in array **$data['Occur']** then
reset timestamp of that event will be just greater timestamp **2013-10-01 00:53:27**.

I have to maintain an array from this which will look like:

$array[0]['occur']='2013-10-01 00:50:27';

$array[0]['reset']='2013-10-01 00:53:27';(respective reset timestamp of 2013-10-01 00:50:27)

$array[1]['occur']='2013-10-01 00:55:11';

$array[1]['reset']='2013-10-01 00:57:17';(respective reset timestamp of 2013-10-01 00:55:11)

On the basis of 'occur' timestamp , i have to find just greater 'reset' timestamp for every 
time stamp value of $data['Occur'] array.

$data['Occur'] array will looks like:

```
[Occur] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Occur_Date_Time] => 2013-10-01 00:50:27
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Occur_Date_Time] => 2013-09-01 00:52:01
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Occur_Date_Time] => 2013-08-01 00:07:48
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Occur_Date_Time] => 2013-07-01 00:06:59
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Occur_Date_Time] => 2013-06-18 10:04:16
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Occur_Date_Time] => 2013-06-17 11:40:50
                )
       )

**and** 

[reset] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reset_Date_Time] => 2014-04-01 00:03:34
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reset_Date_Time] => 2013-09-01 01:09:21
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [reset_Date_Time] => 2013-09-01 00:00:34
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [reset_Date_Time] => 2013-07-01 00:16:14
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [reset_Date_Time] => 2013-06-18 11:05:28
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [reset_Date_Time] => 2013-06-17 12:56:58
                )
       )
```

above array may will have random timestamp , so i cant matched them sequentially. 
i have to match all event occur and reset timestamps . how can i get this?

Comment: Can you explain your question? It is not very clear to me.

Comment: Would it make sense that every pair after the first that are a match would also be a match?

Answer (score 0):

```
function findResetMate($e,$k, $reset) {
    $gap = 10E50+1;
    if ($reset < $e) return false;
    if (($reset - $e) < $gap) {
        $gap = ($reset - $e);
        $mate = $reset;
    }
    echo "EVENT : " . date("M d, Y H:i:s",$e) . " -->RESET<-- " . date("M d, Y H:i:s",$reset) . "<br />\n";
    return true;
}
foreach($data['Reset'] as $r) {
    array_walk($data['Occur'], "findResetMate", $r);
}
```